# Where is rotatelogs on Ubuntu 16.04? (Upgrade Apache 2.2 to Apache 2.4)

Tags: apache, ubuntu

What is the correct path for `rotatelogs` on Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 16.04?

On new Ubuntu 16.04 system installed Apache 2.4, however when using the same config as previous Ubuntu 12 with Apache 2.2 the Apache rotatelogs program is missing.

In previous 2.2 the path was `/usr/sbin/rotatelogs`.

Installed Apache on Ubuntu 16.04 with:

`sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2-utils`

[Rotatelogs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/rotatelogs.html) seems to be documented in 2.4. However the comments indicate path of `bin/rotatelogs`, but that results in error.

Error:

```
(2)No such file or directory: AH00089: Couldn't start ErrorLog process 'bin/rotatelogs /sites/mysite/apache_error_%Y.%m.%d.log 5M'. 
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

In case there are questions the config lines:

*Apache 2.2 (works on Ubuntu 12)*

`ErrorLog  "||/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /sites/mysite/apache_error_%Y.%m.%d.log 5M"`

*Apache 2.4 (both don't work on Ubuntu 16)*

`ErrorLog  "||/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /sites/mysite/apache_error_%Y.%m.%d.log 5M"`

`ErrorLog "|bin/rotatelogs /sites/mysite/apache_error_%Y.%m.%d.log 5M"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the path of an executable, use `which`.

Example usage `which rotatelogs` and it should give your path. Mine is currently `/usr/bin/rotatelogs`

So the `ErrorLog` command would be

`ErrorLog "|/usr/bin/rotatelogs /sites/mysite/apache_error_%Y.%m.%d.log 5M"`